# Faster way to extract one numpy array using another

Tags: python, numpy

I have two large one-dimensional numpy arrays (~1e8+ elements) of the same size.  Array 1 (a1) is an integer indicator value, it tells me the meaning of the values in a2.  Array 2 (a2) has measurement values.  I want to separate the values in a2, based on the values in a1.  I want to iterate over a list of possible values in a1 and select corresponding values (by index) from a2.  Because of the data size and the number of different times I have to do this, it needs to be as fast as possible.

Here's a simple example to hopefully explain my problem more clearly:

```
a1 = [0,   2,   1,   1,   0,   2] # actual values range from 0 to 4095
a2 = [0.5, 2.4, 1.0, 1.2, 0.4, 2.6] # dummy values for example
```

I would like to separate the values in a2 based on the values in a1.  I am saving each separated array into an HDF5 dataset.
So, in the end, I need an array for each value in a1

```
out = [0.5,0.4] # a1 == 0
out = [1.0, 1.2] # a1 == 1
out = [2.4, 2.6] # a1 == 2
```

Currently, I've tried the following:

```
import numpy as np

size = int(1e8)
a1 = np.random.randint(0, 4096, size=size)
a2 = np.random.rand(size)

for i in range(0, 4096):
     ind = a1 == i
     out = a2[ind]
     # more code here to save out to h5 file
```

Based on some timeit testing, np.extract works just slightly faster than this boolean masking approach for large arrays:

```
import numpy as np

size = int(1e8)
a1 = np.random.randint(0, 4096, size=size)
a2 = np.random.rand(size)

for i in range(0,4096):
     ind = a1 == i
     out = np.extract(ind, a2)
     # more code here to save out to h5 file
```

I also tried putting this into a pandas series with a1 as the index, but this was much slower.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

size = int(1e8)
a1 = np.random.randint(0, 4096, size=size)
a2 = np.random.rand(size)
s = pd.Series(a2, index=a1)

for i in range(0,4096):
     out = s.loc[i] #this is WAY slower than numpy
     # more code here to save out to h5 file
```

I'm wondering if there's a faster way of doing this? Maybe with sorting and searchsorted? Is it possible to generate a "database-like index" for a numpy array?

Comment: From your description it sounds like you just want `a2[a1]`, but it's not clear why the integers in a1 only have the limited range. Maybe you could reduce the problem to one of only 10 values and show the desired result based on that to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your both source arrays are plain *pythonic* lists.
So the first step is to convert them to *Numpy* arrays:

```
arr1 = np.array(a1)
arr2 = np.array(a2)
```

Then, to get your expected result as a list of *Numpy* arrays, run:

```
rng = arr1.max() + 1
result = [ arr2[np.nonzero(arr1 == i)] for i in range(rng) ]
```

Details:

- `np.nonzero(arr1 == i)` - generates the list of indices of *arr1*
  where the element contains *i*,
- `arr2[...]` - retrieves elements of *arr2* indicated by the above
  indices,
- `[ ... for i in range(rng) ]` - a list comprehension to generate
  an output array for each value present in *arr1*.

For your data sample you will get:

```
[array([0.5, 0.4]), array([1. , 1.2]), array([2.4, 2.6])]
```

Or if you want your result as a list of **plain** list, change the above
code to:

```
result = [ arr2[np.nonzero(arr1 == i)].tolist() for i in range(rng) ]
```

This time you will get:

```
[[0.5, 0.4], [1.0, 1.2], [2.4, 2.6]]
```